# Scala use argument which is passed to construct the object in other method of the object

Tags: scala, functional-programming

code like this

```
  object Ex10  {
  abstract class Element {
    def contents: Array[String]
    def height: Int = contents.length
    def width: Int = if (height == 0) 0 else contents(0).length

    def above(that: Element): Element =
      new ArrayElement(this.contents ++ that.contents)

    def beside(that: Element): Element = {
      val contents = new Array[String](this.contents.length)
      for (i <- 0 until this.contents.length)
        contents(i) = this.contents(i) + that.contents(i)
      new ArrayElement(contents)
    }

    def beside2(that: Element): Element =
      new ArrayElement(
        for (
          (line1, line2) <- this.contents zip that.contents
        ) yield line1 + line2
      )

    override def toString = contents mkString "\n"

  }

  class LineElement(s: String) extends Element {
    **var contents = Array(s)
    override def width = s.length
    def w = contents(0).length
    override def height = 1**
    def change_contents(source: String) :Unit = {this.contents = Array(source)}
  }

  class ArrayElement(conts: Array[String]) extends Element {
    def contents: Array[String] = conts
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val lineElem = new LineElement("foo")
    println(lineElem.w)
    println(lineElem.width)
    lineElem.change_contents("abcd")
    println(lineElem.w)
    println(lineElem.width)
    println("lineElem [" + lineElem + "]")
  }
}
```

**Result:
 3
 3
 4
 3
 lineElem [abcd]**

In the Programming in Scala book, I am confused with this line `override def width = s.length`, this is a method will be used when invoked.But the argument s for construction the object should be invalid or freed in C++ language for it is a local variable.
Ex

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        A(int a){b = a;}
        int b;
        int f() {cout << a;}
}

int main()
{
    A a = new A();
    a.f()
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

I also debugged the scala code and found that the two fields' (s and contents) value = {char[3]@846}, which may mean that they point to the same memory address.

Could Anyone can explain the arguments passed in scala is pass-by-value or pass-by-reference, and why does the scala like storing the argument which passed to construct the object?

**This is not a difference comparison between two languages' grammar. I want to know the principle of this usage.**

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Through the result s.length is 3. I Guess that the `def height: Int = s.length` is initialized to the determined function value during the object construction.

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". You are really confused.

Comment: @NickyC C/C++ means C language or C++ language. This is a problem about Scala language not C++.

Comment: It's very unclear what that C++ code has to do with Scala and what your question is. If you're trying to understand Scala in terms of C++, stop doing that and approach it on its own terms.

Comment: @George Sorry, i have made a mistake.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am just curious why does scala access these so-called local variable in c++ language like this.

Comment: @NickyC I am disappointed with your irresponsible answer and mark-down action.

Comment: @molbdnilo Through the result s.length is 3. I Guess that the `def height: Int = s.length` is initialized to the determined function value and only waited for invocation. when the object construction. Am i right, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`width` here is a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), and has access to the local variables of its enclosing scope.  You can also make arguments to classes a full member variable by using `val` in the argument list, like `class LineElement(val s: String)`.  Case classes make all arguments members by default.

Both of these syntax features prevent the common boilerplate in other languages that does nothing but copy constructor arguments to member variables.

Comment: I think what you mean is that the reason width can access the variable outside its body (in its environment) is the closure mechanism. I have a question about that when the variable can be freed or it will occupy the memory space all the time until the end of the program? Thanks.

Comment: That variable has the same lifetime as the object.

Comment: Thanks again, I guess the s argument will share with the address where the string is stored with the contents(0), in other words, the s and contents(0) refer to some place where the actual values (Here is string) are stored. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, they refer to the same place in memory.  Immutable references like strings can essentially be treated like values though.